# Generate node/div ID on runtime using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am able to drag and drop having a single id using Javascript.
Now i was wondering is there any way to move these node up and down even after having similar ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the drag(ev) callback you've set id of the dragged element (to be passed via dataTransfer to the drop event callback function):

```
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
```

Then you read this in the drop(ev) callback function:

```
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
```

Now your id is stored in the data variable.
You should get dragged item by:

```
var dragedItem = document.getElementById(data);
```

And now you can drag any element that has an attribute dragable="true" or is draggable by default and has it's own id attribute.

Comment: If i write var drageditem = document.getElementById(data); cloneNode gives an error. And i am dragging div having id4 so how will i move div up and down on click after dropping multiple div with id4??? Thanks